# What is the difference between Javascript Object, Property and Variable, are they all the same?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between a JS:

Object, Property and Variable ?

Sorry I'm new to JavaScript but from the way I'm understanding it is a Variable is a container to store information/data types yes ?

An object is a variable but with several different properties (whereas with a variable you have one property)? name:value pairs

a property is the building blocks of objects? is that what makes an Object an Object? because it is a variable with several name:value pairs? ........

I'm supper confused!!! are all three the same are they like interchangeable?

the only example I can think of is

Human body:
**Cells
Tissues
Organs**

-organs are made up of tissues
-tissues are made up of cells
-cells are tissues, basically lots of cells make up tissues and lots of tissues make up organs.

So basically organs are also cells but they are made up of a lot of cells?

I'm a bit dumb and slow when it comes to learning can somebody please enlighten me?

Explain the differences between them in very simple basic language like your  explaining it to a 10 year old or something please

answers much appreciated,

Thanks :)

ps There may be a part 2 to this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between a global variable and a property of the Global Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439256/is-there-any-difference-between-a-global-variable-and-a-property-of-the-global-o)

Comment: I like to think of a `var`iables as identifiers rather than containers, i.e. it's a little thing that says to the interpreter "this is the reference for where in memory to look to find the data you're after", then that data would have things like "Oh hey I'm a _Boolean_ and my value is `true`" or "Oh hey, I'm an _Object_ and here is a list of my properties and the addresses where you can go look them up"

Answer (score 3):

> the way I'm understanding it is a Variable is a container to store information/data types yes ?

Almost. A variable is a container that stores a **value**. Each value is of a specific **data type**. Common *types* are number, string and Boolean.

Example:

```
var userID = 42;
```

`userID` is a variable. It contains the value `42`. `42` is a number value, i.e. it is of type number.

A JavaScript object is a **value** of type *object*. Objects are not just simple, scalar values, they are "container" values. They can themselves contain multiple different values.

Essentially objects are *key-value* stores, i.e. they contain one or more keys associated with a value. These key-value pairs are called **properties**.

Example:

```
var record = {
  name: 'Paul',
  age: 42
};
```

`record` is a variable. It contains an object as value. The object has two properties, `name` and `age`. `name` holds a string value, `age` a number value.

Comment: May be worth pointing out that all non-primitive data types in _JavaScript_ are _Objects_ (_Array, Date, even Function, Error, etc_), and when you try to access properties on a primitive type it may be wrapped in an object behind the scenes. Also, hey, I'm not 42!

Answer (score 0):

When one refers to 'variable' one typically imagine a container with some memory to hold a value. 
Objects are variables too but dynamically transform to containers of primitives or more-complex values upon Assignment! Complex values can be objects that hold primitive data types or even other objects such in the example below :
`var SNOCounter;` //gives undefined **^** 
`SNOCounter = 3;` 
`AccObjVar =  {firstName:"John", lastName:"Smith"};` //creates an JS "object" variable with two "properties" that hold 'string' type values 
`AccountWrapperObj = {SNO:SNOCounter,AccountName:AccObjVar};` 
The dynamism of object properties is such that although `AccountWrapperObj` which is a JS Object holds a primitive value and Object as its original value. Replacing the `AccountName` property with an integer can be done by just assigning it the integer value (the properties have dynamic data types just like variables in Javascript) 
`AccountWrapperObj.AccountName= 'Albert Einstein';` // changes the type of AccountName from AccObjVar object type to a String

----------Extra Info ---------------
**^** I am not quite clear on the memory assignment part at this stage. Link says there needs to be a bare minimum memory here for referencing the variable and actually assigning it a value.

- [Does declaring a variable in JavaScript with var without assignment consume memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769501/does-declaring-a-variable-in-javascript-with-var-without-assignment-consume-memo)

Answer (score 0):

A variable is a binding to a value in memory and not an object.

The item in a box analogy isn’t quite right. I think that it’s more along the lines of two tin cans connected by a string, one can being the reference(variable) and the other being the value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to JS, so I'll tell what's helping me here

one thing that's helping me is to think about **variables as 'labels', something temporary related to execution** (a metaphor from Luciano Ramalho's Fluent Python book...), and not as 'boxes', a metaphor that I've seen in a lot of tutorials

so variables are temporary, and related to execution of some function, or of the whole script (depending of where they're declared... see the difference of var, let and const for more about this)

**properties, on the other hand, are related to objects**, attached to the obj while it or the property exists; so you cannot create a property that's not related to an obj

```
let myObj = {}; // 'myObj' is the 'label' of the obj we're creating
myObj.prop = true; // we create 'prop', a property of 'myObj', using the dot notation
```

almost everything in JS is an obj, and objs are custom types/structures for data; **functions are also objects, but they're a 'special' kind of obj, we can create and return objects with them** (we can *execute* functions to create/return objs); so

```
let foo; // declaring an empty variable; the word let is related to the scope of the variable, you can use var, let or const when declaring variables
foo = function(){ return {}; }; // foo returns an empty obj
myObj = foo(); // we execute foo() so that myObj is again an empty obj
```

**the value of a property can also be an object**, so we can also do

```
myObj.foo = function(...args){ // receives no or more arguments
    const createProps = (el, i) => { // declares a variable and defines an arrow function
        this[`prop${i+1}`] = el; // uses the index of the argument to create the name of the property, with the argument value
    }
    args.forEach(createProps); // for each arg, create a property
}

myObj.foo('some', 'new', 'properties'); // execute the function, creating new properties in 'myObj'
```

above, the function that creates properties for my myObj is part of myObj, as a property...

so objects and properties have to do with data structuring, how I relate the different kinds of data in my code; and functions and variables - these 'temporary labels' - have to do with execution, doin' stuff, creating objs, and so on... both 'portions' workin' together, of course